# How to set a JSONObject default string for a null value

Tags: android, json

I am passing data to a recycler view using JSON, which works perfectly.

The problem is this, I want to alter the fetched json data. Let's say the user doesn't upload a profile image, that means the database field for image would be blank and our json wont parse any data for data.

So I want to set to a deafault url string if image == null

Heres what ive tried

```
//traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject allTime = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                allTimeEarnersList.add(new LeaderProfile(
                                        allTime.getInt("id"),
                                        allTime.getString("image"),
                                        allTime.getString("username"),
                                        allTime.getInt("earnings")
                                ));

                           //My attempt to set a default value
                            if(allTime.getString("image").equals(null)){
                                    allTime.put("image", "https://10.0.0.0/uploads/blank.png");
                                }
                            }
```

This doesn't work, it doesn't alter the output at all.

It is obvious i'm not doing this right.

Please how can I go about this? what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: does the json return null or a blank? you may want to alter yout if so it checks for both, something like if(all.getString("image").equals("") || all.getString("image").equals(null))

Comment: Also this is assuming your json actually has an "image" key.

Comment: okay thanks, would try it now

Comment: what do you mean by image key? like an image column in the output?

Comment: just tried that, but it didn't work, i'm not certain using .put might be the right approach for me, the json for image returns "image":"",

Comment: the .put should work if your json has an "image" key, what i mean by image key is that your json value is full of key-values, it has the id, name, username and earnings keys, if your image is in blank in the database does the json still has the image key but its value is empty, or does it not have the "image" key at all?

Comment: Also keep in mind that in the code you've shown you dont actually add the put value into the LeaderProfile object you created.

Comment: @ivan is still has an image key, but its empty. Oh please could you guide me in adding it to the LeaderProfile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195475/discussion-between-ivan-and-dr-who).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't putting the value back into the object after you use the .put in the JSON, to avoid blanks/null in an object it's recommended to have a default value in case of nulls in your initializer.

```
public LeaderProfile(int id, String image, String username, int earnings) { 
    this.id = id; 
    if(image.equals("") || image.equals(null) ){ 
        this.image = "defaulturl.png"; 
    }else{ 
        this.image = image; 
    }
    this.username = username; 
    this.earnings = earnings; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use optString

```
allTime.optString("image", "https://10.0.0.0/uploads/blank.png")
```

The optString method is used to retrieve the value for the non-existing key with a default value, which is returned instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block

```
if(allTime.getString("image") != null){
//set imageview glide or picasso
}else{
//set image view glide or picasso but R.drawable.empty_avatar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `get` and the elvis operator `?:`.

The get will return back an `Any` object, which we optionally cast as a String. The elvis operator will ensure any null value will be defaulted to string parameter.

```
allTime.get("image") as? String ?: "https://10.0.0.0/uploads/blank.png"`
```